# Can you rename replacement pattern tokens in views?

Tags: 8, views, tokens

If you insert one or more custom text field (e.g. to include some Twig logic), latter fields will see such blocks as *{{ nothing }}*, *{{ nothing_1 }}* etc. in the replacement patterns.

Can these be renamed? The label and the admin description make no difference.

Comment: Overriding it globally (e.g. changing "nothing" to "something") is easy, just a few lines of code, but if you want to do it per-field it looks like a lot more work

Comment: @Clive How do you override it globally ? It's ok if I could have `custom_text`, `custom_text_1`, would be better than `nothing`.